How can I configure laravel 11 to connect to my Redis cluster?
I have a Laravel 11 app and I'm trying to connect to an AWS Memory DB cluster using PhpRedis.
Following the instructions in the laravel docs and various other sources, I can't get it to connect (the connection simply times out).
However, I can manually connect by creating a PhpRedis RedisCluster object (following these docs) like so:
$c = new RedisCluster(NULL, ['MY_CLUSTER_HOST_NAME:6379'], 1.5, 1.5, true,
NULL, ['verify_peer' => false]);

How can I translate this into laravel's database.php configuration so that I can connect via the Laravel facade?
Here's what I have so far (starting with the defaults from the laravel docs). It seems to be working once I added the context option!:
    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
 
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', 'myprefix'),
            // **Needed to add this for TLS to work**
            'context' => []
        ],
     
        'clusters' => [
            'default' => [
                [
                    'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
                    'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'username' => env('REDIS_USERNAME'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD'),
                    'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
                ],
            ],
        ],


can you share your database config as well and what happens when you try it ? (errors etc)

@apokryfos I added my config. Debugging through the laravel source I added the context option and now it seems to work. Does that look right to you?

From the docs I think you'd put 'stream' => ['verify_peer' => false] in the context to match the RedisCluster params right?

@apokryfos it works without that, and I DO want to verify the peer right?

Typically you do want to verify the peer. I'm just pointing it out because it was in your new RedisCluster call but not in your config so I thought you needed it
